How to handle parameter while setting nginx server-snippet through helm chart
I'm trying to redirect the url through ingress server-snippet annotation in helm chart.
The below hardcoded approach in helm values.yaml works. Is there a way to parametrize the example.com and feed it into helm template command.
keycloak:
 ingress:
   annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
    location = /
     { rewrite ^ https://example.com/auth permanent; break; }

I tried
OPTION 1 : 
URL="https://example.com"
URL_OVERRIDE="|
 location = /
 { rewrite ^ ${URL}/auth permanent; break; }"
        
CHARTS_OPTIONS+=" --set keycloak.ingress.annotations.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet=$URL_OVERRIDE"

OPTION 2: 
URL="https://example.com"
CHARTS_OPTIONS+=" --set keycloak.ingress.annotations.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet=|
  location = /
  { rewrite ^ ${URL}/auth permanent; break; }"

helm template command fails with message
Error: expected at most two arguments, unexpected arguments: =, /, {, rewrite, ^, https://example.com/auth, permanent;, break;, }* 


Setting this exclusively from the command line will be difficult.  You'll need to encode the multi-line string correctly in the shell, and use alternate helm install --set-string syntax to be able to set a values key that includes periods.  It's often tricky to manage things if you're trying to inject bits of Kubernetes manifests as Helm values; could you instead generate this value in your template code?

Yeah. Thought, there might be a direct way to do this through values file. Will generate the values from template itself. Thank you.
